Nextflow cannot find Java, Java is installed
I am trying to install NextFlow on a Linux Unbutu 22.0.4 machine, following this guide - https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/install.html
I have ran everything as described in the guide, with Java version 17.0.10 installed correctly. Following that guide, I have copied the problematic steps below.
When I run
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/nextflow


I get the output
chmod: changing permissions of '/usr/local/bin/nextflow': Operation not permitted

When I run
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/nextflow

I get no response from the terminal
For the final check, when I run
nextflow info

I get the response
bash: /usr/local/bin/nextflow: Permission denied

When I run
nextflow info

I get this
/usr/local/bin/nextflow: line 289: java: command not found
NOTE: Nextflow needs a Java virtual machine to run. To this end:
 - make sure a `java` command can be found; or
 - manually define the variables JAVA_HOME to point to an existing installation; or
 - install a Java virtual machine, for instance through https://sdkman.io (read the docs);
 - for more details please refer to the Nextflow Get Started page at http://docs.nextflow.io.
NOTE: Nextflow is trying to use the Java VM defined by the following environment variables:
 JAVA_CMD: java
 NXF_OPTS: 

Apologies if any of this is super basic, this is the first time I have set up a linux environment from scratch so I am learning this as I go along! I am a little stumped as to what the issue is here, any pointers would be massively appreciated!
Edit: if it is helpful to know, I also installed miniconda according to this guide : https://www.whiteboxml.com/blog/the-definitive-data-scientist-environment-setup
Edit2: Input command-
export JAVA_HOME=/home/synbiopc/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.10-tem;export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH;nextflow

Response-
Usage: nextflow [options] COMMAND [arg...]

Options:
  -C
     Use the specified configuration file(s) overriding any defaults
  -D
     Set JVM properties
  -bg
     Execute nextflow in background
  -c, -config
     Add the specified file to configuration set
  -config-ignore-includes
     Disable the parsing of config includes
  -h
     Print this help
  -log
     Set nextflow log file path
  -q, -quiet
     Do not print information messages
  -remote-debug
     Enable JVM interactive remote debugging (experimental)
  -syslog
     Send logs to syslog server (eg. localhost:514)
  -trace
     Enable trace level logging for the specified package name - multiple packages can be provided separating them with a comma e.g. '-trace nextflow,io.seqera'
  -v, -version
     Print the program version

Commands:
  clean         Clean up project cache and work directories
  clone         Clone a project into a folder
  config        Print a project configuration
  console       Launch Nextflow interactive console
  drop          Delete the local copy of a project
  help          Print the usage help for a command
  info          Print project and system runtime information
  inspect       Inspect process settings in a pipeline project
  kuberun       Execute a workflow in a Kubernetes cluster (experimental)
  list          List all downloaded projects
  log           Print executions log and runtime info
  plugin        Execute plugin-specific commands
  pull          Download or update a project
  run           Execute a pipeline project
  secrets       Manage pipeline secrets
  self-update   Update nextflow runtime to the latest available version
  view          View project script file(s)


As for checking whether the chmod command works, run ls -il /usr/local/bin/nextflow and see if there are xs on the permissions. it should look something like this: drwxr-xr-x.  You dont really need to care about the other dwr stuff, but just check if there are 3 Xs

Hello! "java -v" gives me "Unrecognized option: -v Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit."
"echo JAVA_HOME" gives me "/home/synbiopc/.sdkman/candidates/java/current"

From the permissions, the outputs are all "drwxr-xr-x", so I presume that is okay?

Ah no probs, 'java -- version' yields the below
'openjdk 17.0.10 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.10+7 (build 17.0.10+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.10+7 (build 17.0.10+7, mixed mode, sharing)'

I just tried installing nextflow too. are you sure the output of ls -il /usr/local/bin/nextflow is "drwxr-xr-x"? The correct output after following the steps on the installation guide is: 83224 -rwx--x--x 1 unit1998 unit1998 16068 Jun 12 16:56 /usr/local/bin/nextflow

manually define the variables JAVA_HOME to point to an existing installation Sooo - what does echo $JAVA_HOME say in the terminal? I mean - is it still "/home/synbiopc/.sdkman/candidates/java/current"?

Try logging out and back in. If the java --version command works when you type it at the command line, it ought to work when you type nextflow info on the command line. After logging back in, try running java --version first, and then immediately afterwards type nextflow info in the same command window. It's probably a case of your PATH not having been properly updated, which will be updated after you log back in.

Apologies I was just taking what I thought was the permissions section, this is the full output of this command
22413805 -rwx--x--x 1 root root 16068 Jun 11 17:32 /usr/local/bin/nextflow'

echo JAVA_HOME does still give that output yes, it is /home/synbiopc/.sdkman/candidates/java/current

I have just tried logging out and back in and running those commands as suggested @k314159, I still get the same results unfortunately

would you like to delete the file and retry the nextflow installation again? I m thinking you might not have followed the guide step by step since your file belongs to root. I m guessing you decided to mv the file ahead of time?

It is very possible I have not implemented the guide correctly. Would you suggest deleting sdkman and java and going from scratch, or just deleting nextflow and starting again?

I don't use sdkman. Java under Debian-based systems is already a nest of symlinks, so personally I'd never want to add yet more. This will tell you what your JAVA_HOME actually is: readlink -f "$(which javac)" | sed 's#/bin/javac##' What does it say?

that command gives me /home/synbiopc/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.10-tem/bin/javac
Interesting to know thank you, I am extremely entry level user so I was just following the nextflow guide

It doesn't ;) But your real JAVA_HOME should be /home/synbiopc/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.10-tem. See how you get on with this in the terminal, then you can make it permanent if you wish: export JAVA_HOME=/home/synbiopc/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.10-tem;export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH;nextflow

Hmm I get permission denied when I try to run this command..? Just comparing my output to what you are saying JAVA_HOME should be the only difference is the /bin/javac section on the end?

I re-ran your command and I got /home/synbiopc/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.10-tem

I'm not convinced you're running them exactly as I post them. You couldn't have got what you said you got from my very first command, hence my subsequent comment. That said, the perms look a little odd on nextflow so you should probably do sudo chmod og+r /usr/local/bin/nextflow then post the result of ls -l /usr/local/bin/nextflow

Yes apologies I must have made an error with that, I am not sure what I did wrong! Thank you for flagging.
The result of your last command was -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 16068 Jun 11 17:32 /usr/local/bin/nextflow

That's looking much more realistic. And now in a fresh terminal do export JAVA_HOME=/home/synbiopc/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.10-tem;export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH;nextflow again

Great, and just for my general knowledge (apologies as mentioned I am v new to this) what is the reason for running this next command in a new terminal? the output I got was too long to place in this comment, see the edit2 section of the post for this

OK good - so it's now working. You can now, if you wish, place the first two of those three commands at the end of your ~/.bashrc file, each one on its own separate line, then you won't have to type them in to get nextflow to work properly what is the reason for running this next command in a new terminal? to stop the environment variables concatenating repetitively

Ah okay, thank you that is useful to know! So just to check I have edited the bash file correctly. I did sudo nano /usr/local/bin/nextflow, and added the two commands you shared with me to the end of that file. Now, nextflow info is giving me
Version: 24.04.2 build 5914   Created: 29-05-2024 06:19 UTC (07:19 BST)   System: Linux 6.9.3-060903-generic   Runtime: Groovy 4.0.21 on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.10+7   Encoding: UTF-8 (UTF-8) so this seems to all be in order? Thank you a tonne for the help really appreciate it!

I did sudo nano /usr/local/bin/nextflow, and added the two commands you shared with me to the end of that file That's not what I said at all! Here is what I said: You can now, if you wish, place the first two of those three commands at the end of your ~/.bashrc file

I'm gonna level with you goose I don't know exactly what that file is sorry! If possible could you please point me in the right direction? And I presume you would suggest restoring the file  described to it's original state?

Right. I'm surprised that you weren't curious to do nano ~/.bashrc. Had you done so, you would have found the right file to edit. Definitely restore the other to its former content

Great thank you, apologies for the chaos! I restored the original file, just to be crystal clear the two lines I need to add to ~/.bashrc are sudo chmod og+r /usr/local/bin/nextflow and export JAVA_HOME=/home/synbiopc/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.10-tem;export ?

No! You really need to learn to read more carefully. This is what I said: You can now, if you wish, place the first two of those three commands at the end of your ~/.bashrc file, each one on its own separate line That of course referred to my previous comment. Perhaps you didn't realise that ; is a command separator. We can't type 'lines' into these comments, hence my need to use them. So the first two commands would be export JAVA_HOME=/home/synbiopc/.sdkman/candidates/java/17.0.10-tem;export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Right, apologies I was unaware of the ; separator, and thus confused as to which three commands you were referring to. I am a biologist setting this up for bioinformatic purposes, I have basically zero programming / coding experience! I have now set this up as described, thank you for all your help with this, much appreciated

That's good. Glad it's working

Maybe add the gist as a solution and accept it as answer?
